# Google Play multiple apk distribution

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to make supported devices list for each uploaded apk? Using 8 or 9 API it is impossible to set filter for exact width and height, just screen size *definition*, like normal, large etc., and density. But what if I have 480x800, 480x854 and 540x960 apks? They all overlay heavily in these categories. How do I specify what apk should be loaded?

Comment: @jcw Read twice before posting comments next time :)

Comment: Sorry, similar title, and no answers in your previous post - I jumped to conclusions about this one

Comment: @jcw Sorry too :) Seems that with API level 9 the same device will match categories for 3-4 screen sizes, that's the problem...